# Robbed off vs Robbed of

Tags: commas, off-of

Can you please tell me which one of the following two sentences is right, and why?

He is robbed **off** a huge amount of money? OR
He is robbed **of** a huge amount of money?

Also, is the comma here necessary? -> Can you please tell me which one of the following two sentences is **right, and why?**

Thanks in advance. This is my first question, and the site has been hugely helpful to me so far. You are doing a great job.

Comment: Think *disposed of*, *relieved of*, *get rid of*, ..., not *off*.

Comment: Without the comma, it's one question; with it, it's two questions in one.

Comment: That was very helpful!

Comment: People upvoting such questions might think they're being nice to new visitors, but they're doing the site a disservice.

Answer (score 2):

The comma is helpful in making it clear to the reader that you don't mean 'right and why' where you're treating the interrogative as an adjective, but are asking a new question, the content of which is clear from the antecedent.

Answer (score 1):

"Robbed of," and your comma looks unnecessary but permissible to me.

Comment: But why? Why? :)

Comment: Answers need to be well supported, else it amounts to giving an opinion or making a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> "He **was** (past tense) robbed **of** a huge amount of money."

off (away) vs. of (separation).

> Can you please tell me which one of the following two sentences is right(,) and why?

The comma isn't necessary.

Comment: Why past tense? Why can't the present tense work here?

Comment: Oh, sorry. present tense works too.